# How to validate a character is not included in a string in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, validation

I need to save a **Regex** as text in my database, the users should be able to modify it from the UI, I need to validate the users won't input a **unescaped forward slash (/)** in the form.

I Haven't found anything about excluding characters or if **this is even possible.**

So far, my class looks something like this:

```
class Setings < Trigger
  REGEX = /this is/

  # Validations
  # -----------------------------

  validates :rest_period,   numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }, if: :rest_period?
  validates :custom_regex,  presence: true, format: { with: REGEX, allow_blank: true, message: "must be a valid Regex" },
end
```

I need to validate this since the user could input a character that could break a later function in some other software class.

**I have some RSpec tests for this functionality**

```
describe Settings do
  context "when invalid" do
    subject { Settings.new }

    context "when completion_page] is not a valid regex" do
      before          { subject.completion_page = "^Applicant Information.*" } # This should be valid
      it("has error") { expect(subject.errors.full_messages).not_to include "Must be a valid Regex" }
    end

    context "when completion_page] includes unescaped forward slashes" do
      before          { subject.completion_page = "/^Applicant Information.*/" } # This should be invalid
      before          { is_expected.to be_invalid }
      it("has error") { expect(subject.errors.full_messages).to include "Must be a valid Regex" }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this regex to match string which doesn't contain unescaped forward slash:

```
REGEX = /\A((?!\/).)*\z/
```

The answer for a same question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) explains why we choose regex like that :D

Comment: That won't work. (I made the same mistake in my now-deleted answer.) That's because `"abc/def" == "abc\/def" #=> true`. User input needs to be read key-by-key.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
REGEX = /\A((?![^\\]\/).)*\z/
```

Invalidates strings with `/` not preceded by `\`.